# Integer column fetched with RMySQL can't be converted to double

Tags: mysql, r, type-conversion, rmysql

Well, the conversion with `as.double` appears to work, but then adding a non-integral number gets truncated back to integer.  For example, this is the setup:

```
geo <- fetch.data.from.mysql(...)
> head(geo$total_time)
[1] 1586  165 5339 1586 2895 1178
> typeof(geo$total_time)
[1] "integer"
> typeof(as.double(geo$total_time))
[1] "double"
```

So far everything is as expected.  But then when you try to add 0.5 to it, it says it's a double but it truncates the decimal part like an integer:

```
> head(geo$total_time + 0.5)
[1] 1586  166 5340 1586 2896 1178
> head(as.double(geo$total_time) + 0.5)
[1] 1586  166 5340 1586 2896 1178
> typeof(geo$total_time + 0.5)
[1] "double"
```

The column in the MySQL database is: `` `total_time` int(32) default NULL ``

I really need to add some jitter to this vector, so this is driving me nuts.  Any help would be appreciated.  Finally, sessionInfo():

```
 > sessionInfo()
 R version 2.12.0 (2010-10-15)
 Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

 locale:
 [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

 attached base packages:
 [1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 other attached packages:
 [1] RMySQL_0.7-5  DBI_0.2-5     ggplot2_0.8.8 proto_0.3-8   reshape_0.8.3 plyr_1.2.1   

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tools_2.12.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel stupid now, but this turns out to have been a case where the numbers did in fact have the decimal part, but it wasn't being printed due to `options(digits=3)` in my `.Rprofile`.

```
> options(digits=10)
> head(geo$total_time + 0.5)
[1] 1586.5  165.5 5339.5 1586.5 2895.5 1178.5
```

Moral of the story is: don't trust everything you `print()`.

Comment: +1 That was going to be my suggestion @Daniel, as there is no way I no of for you code to work the way you demonstrated without involving some reduced level of precision in *printing*. Now would be a good time to get rid of that directive from your `.Rprofile`... (Accept your own answer by the way.)

Comment: It would be nice if there were a way to tell R to print at least a decimal point for non-integral numbers, regardless of `digits`.